# Wrong include_path for Codesniffer

Tags: pear, phpcodesniffer, xampp

This issue has been addressed before and I have tried to solutions offered and think I am doing something wrong. I am attempting to configure PHP Codesniffer on a Mac using Mountaion Lion. I don't think it matters, but I ma using XAMMP.  I am getting the following error when I run phpcs.

```
Warning: include_once(PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpcs on line 31

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /usr/bin/phpcs on line 31

Fatal error: Class 'PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI' not found in /usr/bin/phpcs on line 34
```

This error, based on all the searching, is because of an incorrect include_path in php.ini. 
As I understand, this path is supposed to be the directory where pear resides. When I run 
pear config-get php_dir  it returns /usr/lib/php/pear I expected this. 
So I modified the php.ini file (this file is the only php.ini on the system, so it is not grabbing the setting from another file) to read:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php/pear/"
```

This looks right, but I keep getting the same error. I have removed the leading .: and that does not help...and it shouldn't work. I also removed the trailing / and same result. 
Note that phpcs is in the usr/bin directory.
Below is the result of running pear config-show

```
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/lib/php/pear/docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/lib/php/pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /private/tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /usr/lib/php/pear/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/lib/php/pear/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /private/tmp/pear/download
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          /private/etc/php.ini
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /JimS/temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/lib/php/pear/tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/lib/php/pear/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/local/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /private/etc/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /Users/JimS/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /private/etc/pear.conf
```

Any ideas? I am prone to typos, so that is always a possibility, so everything I put here is cut/paste.

Comment: As you change the include_path, is the error message changing to show you the new path? If not, run `php --ini` to see which ini file (if any) it is using.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for the reply. There is only one php.ini on the system. When I run php --ini it returns:Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: Your other php.ini might be being used for Apache or another web server, or it might not be used at all yet. Try copying that php.ini to /etc/php.ini and that can be your command line one that you edit from now on. See if it works once placed there.

Comment: Hi Greg, An odd thing happened. I copied my one php.ini file to /private/etc and ran php --ini This time it recognized the file, but when I ran phpcs I got a bunch of additional errors that looked something like this: PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic link libary .... path .... filename. This error repeated for about 20 different files. I am now looking into those errors. They appear to be related to having different versions of PHP on the system. Mountain Lion comes with its own, and I am running XAMMP. BTW - I configured all this and more on Win 7 in about 10 mins, go figure!

Comment: I do all my PHPCS dev on my mac using the built-in PHP version (I have a VM for testing other versions) and just use copy the default php.ini from /etc. I haven't installed XAMMP so I can't really help with how to configure that. Strange that it wouldn't come with a clean working php.ini for the CLI. You could always use the OS X one: `cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini` to see if it works.

Comment: Hi Greg, I have pretty much decided to just do the codesniffer work on the Win 7 PC and use git to propagate. When I have time, I will rebuild the Mac and install the AMP applications separately using something like Homebrew. I am sure this could be resolved with a careful re-install, but I am unwilling to put in the time / effort and possibly end up at the same place. I really appreciate your help even if I can't call anything an answer. If I solve this, I will reply with my own detailed answer, but I suspect I will simply use Homebrew and the built-in PHP.

Answer (score 7):

There is an excellent article on how to get it up-and-running:

http://viastudio.com/configure-php-codesniffer-for-mac-os-x/

I followed the easy instructions and had it working in no time!

The secret is to fix the include path with these commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Server/Web/Config/php

sudo touch /Library/Server/Web/Config/php/local.ini

echo 'include_path = ".:'`pear config-get php_dir`'"' | sudo tee -a /Library/Server/Web/Config/php/local.ini
```

Comment: Posted for the benefit of those who are seeking a resolution and found this question...

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS High Sierrra `10.3.2` it is 2 simple steps:

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
echo 'include_path = ".:'`pear config-get php_dir`'"' | sudo tee -a /etc/php.ini
```

The last line sets the `include_path` at the end of the `/etc/php.ini` file

Comment: Thanks! it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Working solution on macOs 10.15.5. PHP version used: 7.3.19, installed using homebrew. Pphcs was installed using pear using

```
sudo pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
```

- Step 1. Identify the php version and the php.ini used `php -i | grep ini`. The output will be something similar to what is given below. Pay attention to the value `Loaded Configuration File`. The value corresponding to `Loaded Configuration File` is the file that we need to edit.

```
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
Supported handlers => ndbm cdb cdb_make inifile flatfile
init_command_executed_count => 0
init_command_failed_count => 0
```

- Step 2. Identify the pear path with `pear config-get php_dir`. The output will be a path like `/usr/local/share/pear@7.3`. Copy this path.
- Step 3. Open the configuration file obtained in step 1 and add the following line to it
  `include_path = "PATH OBTAINED IN STEP 2`. In this case, `include_path = "/usr/local/share/pear@7.3"`

In essence, what this does is to load all the Pear files when php cli loads.